# How to Implement the given-Solution to solve circular Navigation problem

Tags: windows-phone-7

This Circular Navigation solution from The link : http://create.msdn.com/en-us/education/catalog/article/nln-serv-wp7

To implement this given-solution , user must do these for the current project:

1.Must use the WindowsPhoneRecipes Namespace in all the pages of the project

2.The current project Must change its Assembly Name to WindowsPhoneRecipes

Please kindly advise if the above are necessary.  Thanks

Would appreciate your help on this implementation thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try the info I wrote in this thread.

[Installing Nonlinear Navigation Service?](http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/t/70315.aspx)

Open the WindowsPhoneNonLinearNavigationService solution to see a working example.

In this you will see the following

- a project WindowsPhoneNonLinearNavigationService - this is a sample project you can run
- you will see a Reference was added to NonLinearNavigationService (you need to add a reference like this in your project)
- a project NonLinearNavigationService (you can include this project in your solution)

Answer (score 2):

I seen in that source code, you have to remove the comment line on WMAppManifest.xml file in properties folder, then you continue with coding.
http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2010/12/13/solving-circular-navigation-in-windows-phone-silverlight-applications.aspx

Here,
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
}
function is there , so you must pass one argument to Page1(again).
In page1(new) button your passing count value. First time the page is loading the count value is 1, the you click page1(new) it pass the count value to page1 and count is incermented.